# How do I know what file to edit and what to do from this error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I added the column name to the users table which is based on the rails/devise gem.  When I click on the admin tab that shows the list of users, I then click on the user name to bring up the edit page for that users profile.  I get the following message.

Showing ~/rails/blog/app/views/users/_user.html.erb where line #8 raised:

```
undefined method `name_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fc716efd730>
Extracted source (around line #8):
6
7
8
9
10
11

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.name_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/edit.html.erb
```

I tried to add:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:edit_profile) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password) }
```

to the application controller, but still get the same error.

1. How do I figure out where to make an modification to make rails understand that name_field is the field about the name ( yes, I looked at the migration and name is in the schema and has been migrated ).
2. How do I get it to accept that field as a defined field?  I can't figure out the voodoo that creates that name_field, so I can't see where to make the change.
3. I used a scaffold to create the user admin pages.  Why did it not create this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name_field` is not a valid form helper as Rails does not dynamically generate form helpers based on column names. Rail's [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest), for the most part, are based off of [valid HTML5 input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

So when you see something like this in your devise form...

```
<%= f.email_field :email %>
```

`f.email_field` is referencing the email HTML input type and `:email` is referencing the attribute. The above helper generates the html...

`<input type="email" name="user[email]">`

So, your form field should use `text_field` instead...

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name" %>
</div>
```